# Problem with laravel/ui in laravel after the last update

Tags: laravel

Can someone tell me what is this?

Cant run `composer require laravel/ui`

```
    $ composer require laravel/ui
Using version ^3.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - laravel/ui 3.x-dev requires illuminate/filesystem ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0].
    - laravel/ui v3.0.0 requires illuminate/filesystem ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0].
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.3, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.3].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[3.x-dev, v3.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Yesterday, i have updated all parts like node,php etc..

Comment: laravel/ui 3.x is compitable for Laravel 8.x. **[look here](https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/155)** May be you need laravel/ui 2.x. **2.4.1** is the latest version of 2x, which was release yesterday

Comment: @sta how can I specify version I want ?

Comment: On `composer.json` file, you need to mention the version you want. Then update composer

Comment: @sta but I dont have laravel/ui line anywhere in my composer.json should I add it manually or ?  And if I do, where should I add it

Comment: add it manually to the "require" object... "laravel/ui" : "^2.4"

Comment: I solved in this way: composer require laravel/ui:^3

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic laravel/ui 3.x is compitable for Laravel 8.x. and laravel/ui 2.x is compitable for Laravel 7.x. and laravel/ui 1.x is compitable for Laravel 6.x.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**In laravel 7 version**

***laravel/ui 3.x is compitable for Laravel 8.x.** look here May be you need **laravel/ui 2.x. 2.4.1** is the latest version of 2x, which was release*

Please run below command:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"
```

**Supported Versions:**

Only the latest major version of Laravel UI receives bug fixes. The table below lists compatible Laravel versions:

```
Version     Laravel Version
1.x         5.8, 6.x
2.x         7.x
3.x         8.x, 9.x
```

[**Look at here**](https://github.com/laravel/ui)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Haronur , it worked for me. I am using Laravel 7